# Translate C code to assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, y86

I have to translate this C code to assembly code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){

 int a, b,c;
 scanf("%d",&a);
 scanf("%d",&b);
 if (a == b){
   b++;
 } 
 if (a > b){
  c = a;
  a = b;
  b = c;    
 }
 printf("%d\n",b-a);
 return 0;
 }
```

My code is below, and incomplete.

```
    rdint %eax        # reading a
    rdint %ebx        # reading b
    irmovl $1, %edi

    subl %eax,%ebx
    addl %ebx, %edi
    je Equal


    irmov1 %eax, %efx  #flagged as invalid line
    irmov1 %ebx, %egx
    irmov1 %ecx, %ehx
    irmovl $0, %eax
    irmovl $0, %ebx
    irmovl $0, %ecx

    addl %eax, %efx    #flagged as invalid line
    addl %ebx, %egx
    addl %ecx, %ehx



    halt
```

Basically I think it is mostly done, but I have commented next to two lines flagged as invalid when I try to run it, but I'm not sure why they are invalid.  I'm also not sure how to do an if statment for  a > b.  I could use any suggestions from people who know about y86 assembly language.

Comment: Most C compilers have a switch that generates assembly for you: gcc -S, cl /Fa, etc...  at least "x86" assembler for you ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did compile this? y86 is a hypothetical language for homework problems

Comment: In the assignment we compile using yas progName.c and then yis progName.yo

Comment: @JoeCortopassi - I believe the assembler ("yas") and simulator ("yis") come with this book: [Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can find online ([1](http://voices.yahoo.com/the-y86-processor-simulator-770435.html), [2](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/hunt/class/2011-fall/cs429/cs429-lectures-v4.html)), the only supported registers are: `eax`, `ecx`, `edx`, `ebx`, `esi`, `edi`, `esp`,  and `ebp`.

You are requesting non-existent registers (`efx` and further).

Also `irmov` is for moving an immediate operand (read: constant numerical value) into a register operand, whereas your `irmov1 %eax, %efx` has two register operands.

Finally, in computer software there's a huge difference between the character representing digit "one" and the character representing letter "L". Mind your 1's and l's. I mean `irmov1` vs `irmovl`.

Comment: If I can;t do something like irmov1 %eax, %efx, then how would I set my efx equal to eax (given that I will now give efx a valid name)...this was the only way I knew how to do this given the notes I have.

Comment: There's no register named `efx`. You can only choose from existing registers. Correct the spelling of the instruction. It ends in "L", not in "one".

Comment: And you need `rrmovl` to move from a register to a register. Read the y86 docs, there's enough info at the links I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Jens,

First, Y86 does not have any efx, egx, and ehx registers, which is why you are getting the invalid lines when you pour the code through YAS.

Second, you make conditional branches by subtracting two registers using the subl instruction and jumping on the condition code set by the Y86 ALU by ways of the jxx instructions.

Check my blog at http://y86tutoring.wordpress.com for details.

Comment: Your link is not related to the topic of this question, and you've failed to indicate it's your own blog.

Comment: Not relevant?  Well, of course the link it relevant.  Clearly Jens, the poster, does not understand Y86 at all, and so the link leads him to a location where he can gain understanding.

Comment: With respect to it being my blog, yes, I stand somewhat corrected.  Actually it is *our* blog, belonging to a couple of guys who enjoy Y86.   Regardless, I was not aware of the need for disclosure, and I stand corrected.